# Returning linked records and avoiding multiple subqueries/loops

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, loops, subquery

I am facing a new SQL database scenario (for me) and I would really appreciate any advice. I am sure  there is a really simple answer, but I can't quite get my head around it. I will try and be as specific as possible...

Client will have many seperate appts in our DB. These appts can be one-off or linked as a series of visits. I am trying to find a specific Appointment event and find all the linked appointments to this event, out of my Microsoft SQL database 2008 R2 DB. I would ideally like to see each linked appt as a separate row in the query results.

All Appts details are in table 1 (lets call it "Appt"). 
The links between the Appt and ***its previous Appt only*** are in Table 2 ("ApptLink"). The ApptLink table includes the ApptId as a FK and the previous linked ApptId (FK)in a sperate column.

Eg. Sample Data

Appt Table

ApptId (PK), DateTime, eventtype, duration, comment, apptstatus, location

ApptLink table

PK, ApptId (FK), PreviousApptId (FK)

I'll try and put it another way. I can return the main appt I am looking for no problems, but when I want to find the previous appt, I need to join the Apptlink table which will show me the previous ApptId only, and to find the previous appt to that I need to find that Id in the apptlink table and its previousapptid and so on... I guess I need to run a Subquery/loop to return the results of that appt as I might have ***30 linked appts***.

I started creating something like below, but I know its not right and there must be a simpler/quicker way than running 30 sub queries. I am feeling like I need to create heaps of sub queries to make sure I get all the previousapptIds, until I return a null, which mean there are no more linked previousapptIds.

```
Select *
From Appt 
Where ApptId in (Select Appt.ApptId, ApptLink.PreviousApptId
                 From Appt 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN ApptLink ON Appt.ApptId=ApptLink.ApptId
                 Where Appt.Apptevent = 'Finish' and Appt.DateTime = '2014-3-1'
                 UNOIN
                 Select ApptLink2.PreviousApptId
                 From AppLink ApptLink2
                 Where ApptLink2.ApptId = ApptLink.PreviousApptId --(from above?)
                 UNOIN
                 Select ApptLink3.PreviousApptId
                 From AppLink ApptLink3
                 Where ApptLink3.ApptId = ApptLink2.PreviousApptId --(from above?)

                 --and so on for 30+ times...

                 )
```

Truly appreciate your assistance.

Josh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a recursive query. You can read how that's done in SQL Server using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks Ownen - never come across this before but i think it will help me out! Will try to post back my solution in case anyone else is in the same boat.